# Active Directory Auhtentication for Sharepoint MVC On-Premises App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, active-directory, authentication, sharepoint-on-prem

Probably a stupid question, but I have some trouble understanding if both normal MVC application Organizational Accounts On-Premises Authentication and On-Premises high-trust app authentication for Sharepoint can/or do use Active Directory for authentication.

My problem is that I'm creating an app for Sharepoint I use Active Directory (Not Azure on the cloud) for the user authentication. Im not sure how I should set this up and if I can go do this by creating the high-trust on-premises Sharepoint app or if I have create a normal MVC app with Organizational Authentication and then find a way to deploy it to Sharepoint as a Provider-hosted one. Is this the way it's done or am I way off? (Please point me in the right direction if I am)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set up an high trust app that uses S2S protocol, because your provider hosted app needs to be accessed only by users who has access to SharePoint, also the app will need permission to access the SharePoint resources.

Follow this blog to [set up an high trust provider hosted app](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shariq/archive/2013/05/07/how-to-set-up-high-trust-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-amp-troubleshooting-tips.aspx).

Comment: thank you! this helped me alot! Especially since Im no the best at googling